# Function runs automatically and can't call Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

A document contains script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(function reset(){
            $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
            userInputSumm = 0;
            userInput = [];
            console.log('reser was executed!');
        });

        $("#reset").click(function() {
            reset;
            /* $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
            userInputSumm = 0;
            userInput = []; */
        });

    });
```

and in page html

```
<p>
    <a href="#" id="reset">Reset all</a>
</p>
```

The function reset executed on page load.

1. How can I prevent it from executing on page load?
2. When I press link `Reset all` the function `reset` does not work? Why?

Comment: remove $ infront of function

Comment: you aren't actually calling `reset` in your click handler. also why don't you use `input type="reset"`?

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering why the downvotes? He clearly showed an attempt to solve his problem, provided enough code, and has a clear question. I just don't get it...sorry rozerro, I'll upvote for a well posted question

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 it isn't useful, it is poorly researched, and doesn't really make any sense. Why would you ever use `reset;`? it's worthy of downvotes for several reasons.

Comment: Yes, the attempt doesn't make any sense. *"I tried `var spaghetti;` but it didn't do anything."*

Comment: ha had my comments removed, so lets try it again, it makes sense because he was attempting to make a function call and needed help why his code wasn't working and because he might not be as strong in programming you refuse to help, not the point of the site, you should know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot

Remove the `$(  )` around your function. - This is what makes it execute automatically.

Then in the button put ()'s after the name `reset()` - This is how you call a function in Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function reset(){
        $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
        userInputSumm = 0;
        userInput = [];
        console.log('reser was executed!');
    };

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        reset();
        /* $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
        userInputSumm = 0;
        userInput = []; */
    });

});
```

Comment: I also using reset(); in a different function whish with $. And that  reret() is inside `if` block but when that if runs then reset() produces an error: processExercise:119 Uncaught TypeError: reset is not a function. Why is that?

Comment: the error is saying it can't find the `reset()` function. So it could be a scope issue, or maybe that `script` isn't imported in the html page

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$(...)` from the function declaration and call `reset()` like a normal function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function reset(){
        $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
        userInputSumm = 0;
        userInput = [];
        console.log('reser was executed!');
    }

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        reset();
        /* $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
        userInputSumm = 0;
        userInput = []; */
    });

});
```

You just want it to be a normal function. When you put it in `$(...)`, jQuery thinks it's a function that'll return a set of selectors, so it calls it immediately. You don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

       function reset(){
            $("#select-result").empty().html("&nbsp;");
            userInputSumm = 0;
            userInput = [];
            console.log('reser was executed!');
        }

        $("#reset").click(reset);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a href="#" id="reset">Reset all</a>
</p>
```

There is no need to have an anonymous function in the click event binding,you can directly set to the reset function

Answer (score -1):

Remove  "$" before your function and add () for call the function.

```
function reset(){
    };

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        reset();
    });
```